# How to get percentage of values which are not null?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm running with `python 3.7.6` and have `dataframe` as follows:

```
     f_value      desc

1    f1            null
2    f2            null
3    f1            TBD1
4    f3            TBD2
5    f4            TBD4
6    f1            TBD5
```

I want to group by f_value and get percentage of on `desc` column: percentage of values which are not nulls.

something like:

```
     f_value      res_prec

1    f1            66%
2    f2            0
3    f3            100%
4    f4            100%
```

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can commapre values for non missing values by [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) and aggregate `mean` for percentage of occurencies, then multiple to `100`, convert to integers, to strings, add percent `%`:

```
df1 = (df['desc'].notna()
                 .groupby(df['f_value'])
                 .mean()
                 .mul(100)
                 .astype(int)
                 .astype(str)
                 .add('%')
                 .reset_index())
print (df1)
  f_value  desc
0      f1   66%
1      f2    0%
2      f3  100%
3      f4  100%
```

**Details**:

```
print (df['desc'].notna().groupby(df['f_value']).mean())
f_value
f1    0.666667
f2    0.000000
f3    1.000000
f4    1.000000
Name: desc, dtype: float64
```